# Regex Validation should allow particular value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a validation to allow only alphabets and characters. No special characters are allowed. But i need to allow one value like 'No Access'. How can i do this?

```
var filter = /^(?=.*\d+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[\da-zA-Z]{6,}$/;
var pass = String(name).search(filter) != -1;
```

name is the value of the textbox.

Comment: you might want ot check that special case manually first, like 'if no access then ... else if matches regex then ..'

Comment: yes.. i can do regex first, then i can do manually for the value.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternation in regex:

```
var filter = /^(No Access|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[\da-zA-Z]{6,})$/;
```